# Check if the functional system is a base of $ (\mathbb R[t]_3 )^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I have problem with this task:

Endomorphism $ F \in L(\mathbb R[t]_3 )$ is given by:

$$  F(p) = 2\cdot p'(t) + (1+t+t^2+t^3)\cdotp(0) $$

Check if the functional system 
$$ f_j^*(p) = F(p)(j) $$for $j=0,1,2,3$ 
is a base of $ (\mathbb R[t]_3 )^*$

I have an idea to solve this in this way
$$p(t) = at^3 + bt^2 + ct + d $$
$$ F(p)(0) = ... = 2c+d = [0,0,2,1]^T $$
$$ F(p)(1) = ... = 6a+4b+2c+4d = [6,4,2,4]^T $$
$$ F(p)(2) = ... = 24a +8b +2c+13d = [24,8,2,13]^T $$
$$ F(p)(3) = ... = 54a + 12b + 2c + 40d = [54,12,2,40]^T $$
but I don't know what I should do next...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ℝ[t]3 is of dimension 4.
A set of vectors is a base of a vector space if it has the same dimension as the space and if the vectors of the set are linearly independent. 
In this case, you already have a set which has as many elements as the dimension (4), so you just have to check linear independency to show that it is a base.

EDIT:
To see if your 4 vectors are linearly independent, you can put them in a matrix and the matrix has to be of full rank.

\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 &2 &1 \\
6 &4 &2 &4 \\
24 &8 &2 &13 \\
54 &12 &2 &40 \\
\end{pmatrix}

$\vdots$ which after few RE steps gives us the following matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
6 &4 &2 &4 \\
0 &-8 &-6 &-3 \\
0 &0 &2 &1 \\
0 &0 &0 &12 \\
\end{pmatrix}

Which is indeed of full rank (4). Thanks to this, your vectors are linearly independent.

You can now conclude that your set of vectors is a base.

Comment: Chmmm. Are you sure that it is correctly?

Comment: This is a method which definitely works. It would maybe help me if you could tell me what you think is necessary for a set of vectors to be called a base.